# Is there a way to have a list in Django that isn't separated by comma's

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am looking to get an array or list of some sort that can be appended to, sort of like this custom form I am using for a many to many field I have.

[image: form list example]

The reason I can't just make another table and use the same form is that each entry on this list may be different.

I have found ArrayField, but we are trying to avoid just using commas.

Comment: What does it matter how it's stored? It's how to display it that's important, and that is up to the template or the form field.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yeah I need any sort of method to display the field

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question from the title is no. List elements are separated by the comma in Python.

Your question is not very clear but it seems that you want to display your list in the template. For that, you need to iterate over the list.

```
{% for element in list %}
    {{ element }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think my question is pretty self explanatory, from the picture of the form I provided. I want to have a form field for data insertion similar to the one I provided above but for an arrayfield instead of a many to many field.